# How to change the data rate between two nodes during the simulation in NS-3?

Tags: c++, networking, ns-3

A Server is connected to an Access point via point to point link of 10Mb/s.

```
PointToPointHelper p2p;
p2p.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue("10Mbps"));
wanIpDevices = p2p.Install (ServerNode, ApNode);
//only relevant code added
```

How can I change the data rate of this link to 5Mb/s after 100 seconds of simulation. I tried the code below but it didn't work.

```
double timeNow = Simulator::Now().GetSeconds();
Simulator::Run();
if (timeNow==100.0)
{
  p2p.SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue("5Mbps"));
}
Simulator::Destroy();
```

Comment: maybe `if (timeNow >= 100.0)` ? (`>=` rather than `==`)

Comment: it didn't worked either :(

Comment: I don't know anything about this, but doesn't `Run()` run your simulation? So instead of measuring time, you just need to do `Run()`twice, and change the rate between them.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65514090/13040392).

The gist of it is that you need to create a function that sets the PointToPointNetDevice's Attribute. Then, use `Simulator::Schedule()` to schedule that function to be called the number of seconds you want into the simulation.