# NS3-How to modify pointopoint channel datarate during simulation run

Tags: c++, ns-3

I'm new to NS3 and looking at the first.cc tutorial.
https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/first_8cc_source.html

In the tutorial two nodes are setup using a point to point link.
I'm interested in changing the datarate of the device/channel during simulation run() and analyzing the delay. E.g, i would like to modify the datarate to 3Mbps around 3 seconds into the simulation.

I found the following link to be the same question I'm asking but there doesn't seem to be an answer.
[How to change the data rate between two nodes during the simulation in NS-3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54129664/how-to-change-the-data-rate-between-two-nodes-during-the-simulation-in-ns-3)

Comment: You can use `Simulator::Schedule` to accomplish that. I also recommend asking the [NS-3 Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/g/ns-3-users), where the maintainers are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think thenewjames' comment is correct. I haven't run this script, but here is an example to get you started.

```cpp
static void
DecreaseDataRate(PointToPointNetDevice *dev) {
    dev->SetDeviceAttribute ("DataRate", StringValue ("3Mbps"));
}

int
main(int argv, char* arg[]) {
// setup simulation ...
PointToPointHelper pointToPoint;
// rest of setup

Simulator::Schedule(Seconds(3), &DecreaseDataRate, &pointToPoint);
Simulation::Start();
}
```